# Connect Visual Studio with Web Server

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7.1, microsoft-sync-framework

I made account with a hosting service and they give me sql username, password and hostname... then I created database, created table and inserted some data. Now I want to connect it to my program (windows phone 7.1) by using Microsoft Sync Framework. Can someone help me with that?

When I go to database explorer and press add connection I see these options but don't know which to use:

- Microsoft Access Database File
- Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5
- Microsoft SQL Server Database File

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this here should help you:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2011/08/01/windows-phone-7-using-local-database-for-application.aspx

Your thinking about the Mobile Platform like it is Windows 7, The Mobile platform deals with Data differently and that blog post should help you understand.

Wp7.0 = Isolated Storage
Wp7.1 = Database, This data base is accessed via Linq.

Comment: That Blog post should help you in every way you need then. It was weird for me at first too but it works out pretty well.

Comment: Before I read it.. I want when I add data to me web server and user goes online, it automatically add new data... Will this happen? I don't mind even if he need to press button to add these new data..

Comment: Yes, it will work exactly like a normal Database just a new local version to better work with the small size of the mobile platform.

Comment: Just preform a function to load the Data at start up so that it updates in the application and deal with it in a user friendly manner so that they like your application and Microsoft will Accept it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21343/discussion-between-loclip-and-keeano-martin)